# Is there an equivalent of document.implementation.createDocument ()? Since this method returns undefined in Google Chrome and Safari

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, dom

The following piece of code works fine in Firefox, but in Google Chrome and Safari method `doc.documentElement.innerHTML` returns `undefined`. Is there another way to create a document from a string (or another way to turn a http-response into a document)?

```
var url = "/myapp/ajax";
    http = getHttpObject();
    http.open("POST", url, true);
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", dropdownId.length);
    http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
    http.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200){
            var doc = document.implementation.createDocument ('http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml', 'html',  null);

//This seems to return undefined
            doc.documentElement.innerHTML = http.responseText;
            console.log(doc);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Some info here: http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/DOMImplementation/createDocument

Comment: Ahh I see that document.documentElement is returning null in Chrome and Safari, but what other way is there to get the http.responseText into a document (so that I can get data with `document.getElementById('foo')`

Answer (score 1):

1. Might this be of any interest?

http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2006/04/easy-xml/

Comment: Not exactly, I am trying to create a HTML document out of the returned string, not an XML document. Now I just do a javascript formsubmit instead of getting the data with an ajax request.